# Populating the Listview with data

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

Okay so I'm having trouble with listviews. I have an array of strings saved with sharedPreferences and i want to access them and with them get the information i need. The strings that are saved are objectIDs from parse.com and through them i can access any of the users data. So what i want is to retrieve every users Name from the column "fullname" and make a list, which i can later click on and get access to their profile. So does anyone understand what i mean? This is what i have and im stuck.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("NotificationIDs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("myStrings", new HashSet<String>());

            for (String s : myStrings) {


                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
                query.getInBackground(s, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                        String name = parseObject.getString("fullname");
                        Log.d("These are the names: ", parseObject.getString("fullname"));

                    }

                });
```

As you can see im using im using "for" to go through all of the Strings (objectIDS) saved. And it works, in logcat it displays the names that i want. But i need to somehow make a list of those names and make them clickable. OnClick it would open a new activity in which the users objectID would be placed and all of the data would be retrieved withit. But thats not that important, the list is though.

//EDIT

I did this but it didn't work. The list ends up blank.

public class UserListForHistory extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list_for_history);


    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idList);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("NotificationIDs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("myStrings", new HashSet<String>());

    for (String s : myStrings) {


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
        query.getInBackground(s, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                mAdapter.add(parseObject.getString("fullname"));
                Log.d("These are the names: ", parseObject.getString("fullname"));
            }
        });



    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_list_for_history, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.parseapp.eseen.eseen.UserListForHistory">



<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ListView

    android:id="@+id/idList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the strings are present, if logcat shows them. The only thing you need is to create an [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) (or any of the subclases if needed) and pass to it the list of strings that are retrieved from the preferences. You can create the list on an [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to retrieve the list of all the names (the for cycle on your code) and just notify the changes when the process is finished